# Once I got a new achievement, design of the activity tab is weird

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I attach a screenshot of the problem. Just happened when I entered my activity to see my progress.

[image]

I have not been able to reproduce it again in Spanish but this is the same browser showing the same page in Meta:

[image]

The thing is that this happens when you have not yet set the tracking for the next achievement or privilege, once set I can't see this layout again.

Comment: Browser? Version? Tried another? Some other device?

Comment: Browser: Firefox 51, I haven't tried another. I suspect that the problem is that the string is too long. I'll try to get another privilege and check out with more detail.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [this question](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/263) on the Spanish SO Meta.

Answer (score 7):

Fixed:

[image]

Also note that I have fixed the text (it said "track the next badge").